# A missing paper by Auslander? 

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

I was reading Auslander's talk at the 1962 ICM (beginning of Section 2 on this [page](http://mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1962.1/)). At the end, the reference began:

> [1] M. Auslander, Modules over unramified regular local rings, Illinois. J. Math. 5 (1961), pp. 631–647.
>
> [2] M. Auslander, Modules over unramified regular local rings II, Illinois. J. Math. (To appear).

The trouble is, I can not find [2] on MathSciNet or Google. I also looked at his Selected works without luck. Of course, there are many papers that are [forthcoming but never materialized](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48477/never-appeared-forthcoming-papers), but this one even has the  journal name attached to it! So

> What happened to Auslander paper [2] above?

Note that [1] is an influential paper (still being quoted very recently). I enjoyed it a lot, and would really like to read [2].

UPDATE: both Professor Buchsbaum and Professor Reiten have graciously replied to my query about this missing paper. Unfortunately, neither of them know what happened.

Comment: The only person I can think of who might have direct knowledge is David Buchsbaum.  

Comment: @Graham: good point. May be Idun Reiten as well? Perhaps I should try emailing them. 

Comment: Idun was a child back then -- she got her PhD in 1971.  I think emailing David is probably the best bet.

Comment: @Graham: Yes, but their collaboration is longer. Also, she edited his Selected Works. I just emailed both, let's see. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His "Selected Works" (AMS: http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CWORKS-10) lists on Chapter II, two articles with the same title "Modules over unramified regular local rings"

Comment: Yes, the second one is a reprint of his ICM talk. 

Comment: @Zaldiva: compare that with Auslander's ICM talk linked above: http://books.google.com/books?id=g2mI0cHQKNQC&lpg=PA193&ots=rvGG2AE770&dq=modules%20over%20unramified&lr&pg=PA237#v=onepage&q=modules%20over%20unramified&f=false

Comment: @Zaldiva: but thank you for trying. 

Comment: I will accept this answer for now to prevent the question from being bumped to the top frequently. If anyone knows what happened, please add your answers.  