# Tangent coalgebras and hyperalgebras

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

Takeuchi's [On coverings and hyperalgebras of affine algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.2307/1997233) references [Tangent coalgebras and hyperalgebras. I](https://doi.org/10.4099/jjm1924.42.0_1) and II, with II being listed as submitted to [MAMS](http://www.ams.org/publications/ebooks/memoirs).  [On coverings and hyperalgebras of affine algebraic groups. II](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=429929) also cites both papers, now with II listed as 'to appear'.  [On coverings and hyperalgebras of affine algebraic groups. III](https://doi.org/10.2307/2374192) does not mention "Tangent coalgebras and hyperalgebras. II" at all.

This could usually indicate a planned paper that was never written (indeed, I checked [Never appeared forthcoming papers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48477/never-appeared-forthcoming-papers) to see if it was mentioned there), but [On coverings and hyperalgebras of affine algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.2307/1997233) cites results from "Tangent coalgebras and hyperalgebras. II" by number, and, again, it is listed there as submitted, leading me to believe that it was actually written.  Does the paper exist under some other name?  Was it withdrawn due to an error?